# add_action not working from internal file of plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used this on my class but it is not working

```
add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'funname'));
```

funname function is not calling.function is public.I have refered this url https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48085/add-action-reference-a-class but still not solved my problem

CODE:

```
class Test {
    public static function Create() {
        return  $testObj = new Test();
    }
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'funname'));
    }
    public function funname(){
    echo "tes2t";exit;
    }
}
 $ObjTest = Test::Create();
```

**UPDATE:**

This code call funname if i put code into theme's function.php file but not working when put it on plugin file.

**UPDATE 2**

I have written this line on plugin file directly

```
add_action( 'admin_init',  'funname'  );
function createAdminFromData(){
    echo "pre";exit;
}
```

If i put above code on plugins main file it is working but i have main file of plugin and from that one another file is called where add_action is not working..don't know why?

Comment: $this is only available when you instantiate the class but your method when you call it is static.

Comment: I have tried after removing static from method but still it is not working

Comment: Instantiate the class

Comment: how to Instantiate the class?

Comment: try to call object at the end of code and remove create function


      $var = new Test();

Comment: another is only  test::Create();

Comment: @BilalAhmad: I have tried that but not working on plugin file

Comment: follow this code and then check what will happen

   public function __construct(){
  add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'inits' ) );
 }

 public function inits(){
     //Hook for adding admin menus
  add_action('admin_menu', array( $this, 'funname'));
 }
$var = new test();
and then call object in last and remove your code

Comment: @BilalAhmad: i have tried this and even tried above updated code in plugin file but not working

Comment: just tried your code with `add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'funname'));` in a plugin and it works. if it works on functions.php I don't see why it shouldn't on a plugin: maybe there's something else that interfere? does it echo an error (having WP_DEBUG enabled) ?

Comment: @d79 : in main file i have included that file within add_menu_page callback function and admin_init is called too early may be before add_menu_page.

Comment: add_menu_page should be called on admin_menu action (be sure that's the case), just before admin_init (as you can see [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request)), so it should work